# No matching function to call Std::find?

Tags: c++, qt, stl

I am trying to do:

```
std::find(images_map.begin(), images_map.end(), current_rgb));
```

where:

```
QRgb current_rgb;
QMap<QRgb, MI*> images_map;
```

but I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find(QMap<unsigned int, MI*>::iterator, QMap<unsigned int, MI*>::iterator, QRgb&)
```

Comment: Are those `QMap` and `QRbg` classes from Qt?

Comment: Hmm... mixing Q. T. and S. T. L. seems like asking for P. A. I. N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`QMap::find()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmap.html) method instead.

Comment: voted +1, but tell him the reason: the built in find much faster. Built in find price is abiut _log(n)_ against standard find's _n_.

Answer (score 9):

The reason is because `find` expects the `value_type` of the container to be the same as the searchee type passed in to `find`. You passed in just the key, not the key and value.

Instead, use the `find` method on the container itself (which also has the benefit of being logarithmic instead of linear time complexity).